# Кто поможет разобраться в понятиях? Hibernate, JPA в Spring

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-jpa

Точнее я не очень понимаю, вот такие моменты.

Я понял, что JPA это такая технология которая помогает отображать объекты Java в базах данных.

Hibernate это конкретная реализация этой технологии. Которая предоставляет методы для реализации своего кода.

Я добавляю в pom.xml зависимость

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

В своем приложении я определею сущности (Entity), связи полей OneToMany, ManyToMany, ManyToOne.
Создаю репозитории, которые которые расширяют интерфейсы JpaRepository или CrudRepository.

Составляю методы типа findByFiled() и т.п.

Так же я использую различные аннотации полей сущностей для валидации, поля Id, указания имен таблиц и колонок.

Теперь вопросы:

1. Где здесь Hibernate?
2. Подключаю ли я зависимостью приведенной выше Hibernate к своему проекту?
3. Если да, то тогда что ознают другие зависимости вида:

```
 <!-- Hibernate -->
        <!-- to start need only this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for JPA, use hibernate-entitymanager instead of hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- optional -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-osgi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-proxool</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-infinispan</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: в спринге есть уже hibernate и ту кучу мусора тебе подключать не стоит

Comment: spring-boot-starter-data-jpa имеет транзитивные зависимости, в том числе Hibernate.

Comment: Стоит еще добавить, что в spring-boot-starter-data-jpa стоит наиактуальнейшая, стабильная версия hibernate.

Comment: То, что ты пытался подключить - так обычно делают, если это не spring-проект

Comment: Т.е. я работаю непосредственно с Hibernate? Все что делаю подключая spring-boot-starter-data-jpa это будет Hibernate.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Вопрос у меня собственно возник из-за того, что я пытался сделать собственную аннотацию валидации и как я понял после долгих раскопок, у меня не отрабатывал autowired и это как то связано с Hibernate. В общем, я понял что мне надо копать в сторону persistence.xml но я вообще пока не понимаю, что мне надо указывать там, чтобы autowired отработал. А autowired у меня не отрабаотывает в имплементации ConstraintValidator. Кто нибудь с этим может помочь разобраться? Если надо я сделаю отдельный вопрос и распишу суть проблемы.

Comment: @AlexanderLopatin Где можно посмотреть пример вашей валидации?

Comment: Писал на англ. StackOverflow, там мне ссылку кинули но я пока не пойму что мне делать, пока понял как расписал в комментарии выше. Если не сложно можете посмотреть там мой вопрос. [Ссылка на вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56921374/my-validator-fails-when-userrepositary-try-to-save-new-user-in-database)